How much of Bangladesh's trade with China is by sea vs by road+rail?
Bangladesh only borders India and Myanmar by land, but trades a fair bit with China, I understand. On a quick search, back in 2019, PM Hasina even offered China some kind of CPEC-like access to Bangladeshi ports. However, I imagine there are some geographic and perhaps political hindrances to such a deal, in the case of Bangladesh. (Unlike in Pakistan, the financing of Bangladeshi port developments is a more complicated affair, for instance.)
How much of China-Bangladesh trade is currently done by sea vs by road+rail?

Relevant: https://china.docshipper.com/en/freight-shipping-china-bangladesh/ "Did you know that trains could also swim? That's right! An invisible line of tracks paved in the open ocean connects China and Bangladesh, an unparalleled feat of rail freight that traces back to its inception in the 1990s." See also https://orcasia.org/article/589/economic-ties-between-china-and-bangladesh

@ohwilleke - "An invisible line of tracks paved in the open ocean connects China and Bangladesh." That's a very confusing statement from that article. Is this just an extremely flowery way of talking about loading freight transported by train onto boats? Do they mean a bridge (not invisible)? It sounds as if they are talking about train tracks below the water line in the ocean but I can't find any such project and I doubt any engineers would have thought that was a good idea to build instead of a bridge. There is an underwater tunnel in Bangladesh, but not to China and not in the ocean.

@Obie2.0: naah, it's just talking about direct rail transport from China to Bangladesh. Pretty spammy/SEO page though. Has no trade volumes though, by any of the routes is talking about, so it's pretty useless as far as my Q goes.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever - I do know there are direct land rail routes from China to Bangladesh that go through India, but I am flummoxed as to how they represent "an invisible line of tracks paved in the open ocean."

@Obie2.0 It is dry humor. The absurdity is supposed to tip you off that it isn't serious. In fact, as the link explains (not particularly clearly) with a map, the typical rail trip from China to Bangladesh is from China to Europe by rail, then from Europe to India by rail, and then from India to Bangladesh by rail. This is still usually faster than transportation by freighter ship, but is obviously slower than air freight. Also, most land goods from China to Bangladesh are by truck over roads rather than by rail, often somewhat more directly.

Also, FYI, as noted in the second link in my first comment: "Bangladesh's main exports to China include knit t-shirts, tanned equine and bovine hides, and light rubberised knitted fabric, China's top exports to Bangladesh are vaccinations and refined petroleum."

@ohwilleke - Dry humor or (AI-generated?) SEO weirdness?

@Obie2.0 AI isn't that humorous. When it says something untrue is just BS's and doesn't make a joke about something. And, honestly, I don't think that the link in question is AI-generated.

@ohwilleke - You do not have to go to Europe. The Iran-Turkmenistan rail link connects south and north Asian networks.  But the whole trip would involve several changes in gauge (as well as some politically difficult frontiers) so best done by container, and if you are going to do that you may as well use a ship.

@Henry The link says that this is what is actually done, whether or not it is necessary.
